# Windows Repairs Itself After Ubuntu Boot

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, 12.10

I have a custom built computer in my home which was running Windows 7 primarily. After I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and upgraded to 12.10, Windows 7 has to perform startup repair after every Ubuntu boot up. For example, I am using Ubuntu for my everyday work, but when I switch to Windows to play one of my steam games, windows fails to boot, and it switches to the recovery partition to "repair windows" then boots windows. The whole process takes about 20 minutes, which is quite annoying. Anyone know why this is happening or what I can do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

look at this page

- http://thameera.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/restoring-the-windows-mbr-using-a-ubuntu-live-cd-or-usb/

it helped me to fix windows boot loader after i run commands i booted from windows dvd went to restore options and started boot repair ,but then i had to reinstall grub via ubuntu live cd cause it was gone.

Comment: Yes I understand what this does, it restores the windows boot loader, essentially removing grub. But then I can't boot Ubuntu. So I restore grub, and then I'm back in the same position.

Comment: no not quite correct. After i restored win mbr grub was gone but i fixed it booting with ubuntu live cd.The are a lot of info hot to restore grub. Then after i updated grub it was 'windows' option to boot in list. I also installed burg manager cause it detect other systems fine

Comment: The windows option is there in grub, it detects the other system fine, it's just that when that system is selected, it has to do a "boot repair". Windows doesn't even tell me what it's doing, just to be patient.

Comment: the link i posted with commands fixing windows mbr or boot repair problems if you want.it helped me..